# Force lowercase hostname in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've set my computer name to lowercase in the system properties.

[image: System properties]

In `cmd.exe` it shows as lowercase.

[image: cmd.exe]

However, in Windows 10 Bash it shows as uppercase, even though the `/etc/hostname` file has been updated to be lowercase.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The aesthetics of this annoyed me as well. Rather than try to get `hostname` to return something lowercase I simply attacked how `bash` displayed the prompt. I editied `.bashrc` (which is specific to the install of windows and hence is unlikely to be reused on a different computer) to do the following to the prompt variable `PS1`

```
# Annoyingly the windows hostname is UPPERCASE which really doesn't look
# good on linux. So for this machine I'm going to grab the hostname and
# hardcode it into the prompt
HN=`hostname`
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@${HN,,}\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@${HN,,}:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@${HN,,}: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

The above essentially hard codes the lowercase name of the machine into `PS1` when it is created using the `bash 4.0` feature that `$(A,,)` converts the string A to lowercase. Whilst not an elegant solution to the problem this does make the shell look like a more normal linux shell!

Comment: You can also use `${HOSTNAME,,}` in `~/.bashrc` directly without needing to create a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: [This has now been implemented](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/860); the capitalization you set in the system properties will now be preserved.

I was having the same problem. Turns out you can't just change /etc/hostname from within Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (BUW) because /etc/hostname is generated every time you start it. BUW seems to use the NetBIOS name of your computer to generate /etc/hostname which, according to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724220(v=vs.85).aspx), is "represented in uppercase where the translation algorithm from lowercase to uppercase is OEM character set dependent." When you rename your computer in windows through `Settings > System > About` or `Control Panel > System and Security > System`, it retains the capitalization you give it but the NetBIOS name is converted to all uppercase. That being said, it is possible to change the NetBIOS name to be lowercase, using the Windows API function [`SetComputerName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724930(v=vs.85).aspx). Here's a little C program (**non-unicode**) that sets the NetBIOS name to its first argument (requires admin privileges):

```c
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <sdkddkver.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <New NetBIOS name>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (SetComputerNameA(argv[1]) == 0) {
        LPSTR error_message = NULL;
        DWORD error_code = GetLastError();
        FormatMessageA(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL,
            error_code,
            0,
            (LPSTR)&error_message,
            0,
            NULL
        );

        fprintf(stderr, "SetComputerNameA error (%lu)", error_code);
        if (error_message != NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, ": %s", error_message);
            LocalFree(error_message);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        printf("NetBIOS name set to \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Use it at your own risk, as I'm not entirely sure if having a non-uppercase NetBIOS name has any adverse effects (it might break things that rely on DnsHostnameToComputerName). Ultimately I'm not sure if it's intentional/necessary for BUW to use the NetBIOS name; [I asked about it](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/860) on BUW's issue tracker.

Alternatively, if you don't want to change the NetBIOS name, you could devise some way to change the hostname every time BUW is started using `sudo hostname prophet-w10` (and then `exec bash` to make it show up in the prompt).